# Number to String

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

## Number to String

### Instructions

Convert a signed 32-bit integer to a string (base-10 preferably) without any string formatting calls (or built in type coercion that will directly convert a number to a string).

Negative numbers must include leading `-`.

### Score Calculation

Shortest byte length; Tie breaker by efficiency (execution time)

Comment: Eh, another [Do X without Y](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/48934) challenge.

Comment: @LeakyNun You have a problem with this challenge?

Comment: Can we turn an integer into the character of its codepoints?

Comment: How is a string formatting call defined?

Comment: String functions that are designed specifically to do exactly what the challenge is, like printf

Comment: Is `toString()` allowed?

Comment: Nothing that trivializes the challenge into a single function call that directly converts the value to a string (as many languages can do)

Comment: We call that a built-in.

Comment: Built-ins are fine, if they're not string formatting builtins

Comment: Can we convert single digits to string directly?

Comment: Functions that convert integers directly to a string are not string formatting builtins.

Comment: Since you very clearly understand, why not give it a shot

Comment: Then how can we convert anything to string at all? What functions are allowed? 1. can we cast an integer into a character? 2. can we convert single digits to strings directly?

Comment: Can we have a positive sign?

Comment: Casting is fine yea, but type coercion defeats the point if its doing the exact purpose of the challenge

Comment: Basically it should emulate itoa

Comment: Can we convert integer `1` directly to string `"1"`?

Comment: What base? 2? 10? 16? 256?

Comment: if you can do it "directly" in some way that isn't type coercion, using a mathematical approach

Comment: Is unary output okay?

Comment: If we take a string from STDIN as input can we cast it to an integer with a builtin?

Comment: Re [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/86778/number-to-string?noredirect=1#comment212984_86778): `itoa` isn't the only function in the world.

Comment: @quartata yea that would be fine

Comment: Can we convert integers that are not the input into strings?

Comment: @NickT I was thinking base 10, though if you have something clever for another common base I would say it was fine personally

Comment: Is unary output okay?

Comment: @LeakyNun That would kind of defeat the purpose lol

Comment: Then state it clearly in your question.

Comment: Unary is base 1; so are you restricting the base?

Comment: @NickT You could do another base if you wanted, unary would just be a loop appending the digit N times so its kind of silly

Comment: Then disallow it clearly in the question.

Comment: Are leading zeroes allowed?

Comment: @LeakyNun yea, if they lead a valid result

Comment: It's a nice idea, but there are several problems with this challenge: (1) _base-10 preferably_: saying "preferably" doesn't make much sense here. Either force it or not. What bases are allowed? (2) _without any string formattting calls_ is a little ambiguous. Are base conversion functions allowed, even if they output the characters representing the digits (i.e. a string)? (3) _Tie breaker by efficiency (execution time)_: execution time varies with the computer and input. How will you exactly measure it?

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>61</s> <s>57</s> <s>46</s> <s>45</s> 42 bytes

Apparently this is what you want.

Apparently Leaky Nun saved me 17 bytes.

Output in binary:

```
f=n=>n<0?"-"+f(-n):n?f(n>>1)+"01"[n%2]:"0"
```

Output in decimal:

```
f=n=>n<0?"-"+f(-n):n<10?"0123456789"[n]:f(n/10|0)+f(n%10)
```

Comment: Apparently casting digits to a string is not allowed.

Comment: Apparently you can use binary.

Comment: Apparently `n-a*10` is `n%10`.

Comment: Apparently `n/2|0` is `n>>1`.

Comment: @LeakyNun Aprparently I had that, but I put the wrong version up :P

Comment: Apparently `f(n%2)` is `n%2`.

Comment: @LeakyNun that would be casting a number to string, which I think is against the rules

Comment: Apparently I am stupid.

Comment: Apparently `f=n=>n<0?"-"+f(-n):n?f(n>>1)+"01"[n%2]:"0"` works (Firefox 47.0, JS 1.5)

Comment: 'Apparently' should be the name for a new programming language. Kinda similar to 'Actually', actually. ;) And lol at the "**Apparently** Leaky Nun saved me 14 bytes."

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>14</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
”-“”<?0³AD+48Ọ
<0”-x³AD+48Ọ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=PDDigJ0teMKzQUQrNDjhu4w&input=&args=LTEyMw)